# Jasper reports add static text row in table

Tags: jasper-reports

Currently i am displaying table in jasper reports like this

```
Col1   |  Col2   |  Col3   |  Col4   
------------------------------------
Row1C1 | Row1C2  | Row1C3  | Row1C4
Row2C1 | Row2C2  | Row2C3  | Row2C4
Row3C1 | Row3C2  | Row3C3  | Row3C4
Row4C1 | Row4C2  | Row4C3  | Row4C4
```

But now i want to make table like this

```
Col1   |  Col2   |  Col3   |  Col4   
------------------------------------
Row1C1 | Row1C2  | Row1C3  | Row1C4
Row2C1 | Row2C2  | Row2C3  | Row2C4
Added static row here with colspan
Row3C1 | Row3C2  | Row3C3  | Row3C4
Row4C1 | Row4C2  | Row4C3  | Row4C4
```

is it possible or not?
if yes then how can i add static row in table?

Comment: What is the condition on which you want to insert the static row? I mean if it should be after each X rows or when some specific value appears in the input data source or you only want to separate table into two parts?

Comment: @cgrim above `static row` is for enable records and below `static row` is for disable records. we need to show all records from table(database). We need to put single row with `static text` between those records. There are only one table And i have also index for static row. just need to put static text with colspan at that rowindex. but dont know how to put that static row

Comment: In this case you can achieve it by using two separate subreports separated by static text. First subreport will filter data set to show only enabled records and the second subreport will filter data set to show only disabled records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using data groups. Here is an example how to achieve that:

```
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM some_table ORDER BY flag]]>
</queryString>
<field name="col1" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="col1"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="some_table"/>
</field>
<field name="col2" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="col2"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="some_table"/>
</field>
<field name="flag" class="java.lang.Bolean">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="flag"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="some_table"/>
</field>
<group name="flagGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{flag}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="39">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{flag}]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="380" height="20" uuid="d4d760c5-0587-4bd7-973a-de1d9b0c8da6"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Any static text to separate groups]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="330" height="1" uuid="b00741f6-3d2c-4cca-a3fe-397aa7fbf906"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="330" height="1" uuid="0f30d1bc-30ef-48e9-b40e-ab4a3e2b1ffc"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

It will group rows using `flag` field and you can insert what you want in the `groupFooter`, for example `staticText`, `line`, `rectangle` etc.

Here is the preview:

[image: Preview of using data groups]

And you can find more information about groups on JasperSoft Wiki: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/groups

---

**Update:** In case of using `subDataset` and `jr:table` it is similar. At first define `group` in the `subDataSet`:

```
<subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="bb794b3a-5505-492a-8b9f-500b274a8334">
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[col1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[col2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="col3" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[col3]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="flag" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[flag]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="flagGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{flag}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
</subDataset>
```

And then add group footer (or header) definition in `jr:columnGroup` of `jr:table`:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="0e226f43-fb2c-43df-baa8-4cf91b3e0523">
        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{reportData})]]></datasetParameterExpression>
        </datasetParameter>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:columnGroup width="210" uuid="1b2e36c1-0c14-48a0-97b8-66fa4330a71a">
        <jr:groupFooter groupName="flagGroup">
            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="210" height="30" uuid="840fd833-5895-47d0-b63f-dd058a936a8a">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{flag}]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Any static text to separate groups]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </jr:cell>
        </jr:groupFooter>
...
    </jr:columnGroup>
</jr:table>
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. I have `<subDataset>` and your `<group>` tag code is not working on `<subDataset>` so do you have any idea how to use `<group>` tag in `<subDataset>` tag?

Comment: So you have report with one master query (`dataset`) and for each item form the master `dataset` you have `subDataset` and here you would like to render table separated by static text using enabled flag - is it correct? And you are rendering items from `subDatset` by `subReport` or how?

Comment: I am not using any query in jasper reports, I can pass List of Object from JAVA class to jasper reports as a parameter, and `<datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{reportData})]]></datasetParameterExpression>` using these code in table for get data from List.

Comment: I updated the answer with example for `subDataset` and hope it will help.

Comment: `Report design not valid : 1. Element reaches outside table group footer contents height: y = 101, height = 21, cell available height = 21. 2. Element reaches outside table group footer contents width: x = 5, width = 548, cell available width = 548` I am getting this issue

Comment: You should change `jr:cell` and `reportElement` height and width used in an example to dimensions used in your report.